# Terraform RDS and Certificate Authority

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate, terraform, certificate-authority

Using Terraform resource `aws_db_instance` I don't see a way to configure the Certificate Authority.

This is fine in most regions except GovCloud.

At the moment GovCloud is transitioning between CA's and by default, Terraform uses the old CA.

It is possible to configure using boto3, but this client wants everything in Terraform.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue. 
It would seem that GovCloud have changed the default CA to the latest CA.